# How make the toolbar above default keyboard with React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

How can I make a button over the keyboard by default using React Native?
I mean the buttons for the Native keyboard (do not change the keyboard, just add as the prefix above)

[image]

Comment: There is a build in solution in RN these days. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2018/03/22/building-input-accessory-view-for-react-native

Answer (score 10):

Use `KeyboardAvoidingView` component from `react-native` like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, KeyboardAvoidingView, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { Header } from 'react-native-elements';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
                <Header
                    outerContainerStyles={{ ... }}
                    centerComponent={(
                        <Text style={{ ... }}>
                            Test Screen
                        </Text>
                    )}
                />
                <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <TextInput
                        style={{ ... }}
                        value={ ... }
                        onChangeText={() => { }}
                    />
                </View>
                <KeyboardAvoidingView
                    behavior='padding'
                    style={{ backgroundColor: '#4099FF' }}
                >
                    <Text>
                        Toolbar
                    </Text>
                </KeyboardAvoidingView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Then you have this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if your app is not full screen you can use `position:absolute` and `bottom:0` on `<View></View>` component that you want to be on top of the keyboard.